# Multi tenant (SAAS) using nodejs sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multi-tenant, saas

I am trying to build a multi tenant ( / Software as a service) using nodejs and postgres, sequelize as ORM. I decided to go with separate DBs for each client, rather than having single DB with all table having the extra column, because of security reasons. I achieved the result, but performance was not good, since i have to initialise models for each DB according to sequelize(for almost each request). Is there any better way to do this? Am I missing something in sequelize?

Comment: Use pools with single database (Postgres) you will have far better scalability and less headaches

Comment: Maybe post some code? FWIW, you should only need to initialise your models once (you definitely don't need to redefine them on each request). You can keep your separate DBs if you wish - simply create a sequelize instance for each db using the releveant connection details and pass your model definitions to each one at app startup.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mohamedsameer72/how-we-build-the-multi-tenant-saas-product-using-node-postgres-sequelize-c66a085a42ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the schema approach to multi tenancy in Postgres. I'm no authority on security but it should be better than table based multi tenancy. Disaster recovery should also be slightly easier than table based MT, but still worse than with separate DBs.

I managed to implement this in Sequilize using ES6 Proxies. This puts a hard requirment on your Node version, but if you're willing to use at least v6.9.2 you could give my lib a try:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-multi-tenant-enhancer

Answer (score 4):

A quick implementation of my comment above.

app.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const connections = {
  client1: new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/client1'),
  client2: new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/client2'),
  client3: new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/client3'),
};

const User = require('./models/user');
const Post = require('./models/post');
const Comment = require('./models/comment');

Object.keys(connections).forEach(connection => {
  connection.define('User', userColumns);
  connection.define('Post', postColumns);
  connection.define('Comment', commentColumns);
});
```

models/user.js:

```
module.exports = {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING
  // etc, etc
};
```

Obviously whatever server framework you use you'll need to detect (from the url I imagine) which client connection to use for a given request.

Alternatively, consider writing a single-connection app and deploying multiple instances of it (I'm doing this currently). Might be a simpler choice if you're set on separate DBs.

Comment: How scalable is this solution? What if I have thousands of databases, and I create an instance for each?

Comment: @TFischer that's probably a question for your DB server. Node shouldn't have a problem forwarding that many connections, and I can't imagine PG will have a problem serving them.

Comment: PG has a default of 100 concurrent connections, three of which are reserved for super-user connections, though it can be modified. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-connection.html  -- more tot he point, though, 1000s of connections, if they all are used at the same time, will likely start degrading PG performance pretty severely.